# JAXB javax.xml.bind.PropertyException

Tags: jaxb

I am getting the below error when i try to read XML file that has some japanese characters.

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: jaxb.encoding
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.getProperty(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getProperty(UnmarshallerImpl.java:423)
at com.jaxb.JAXBTest.main(JAXBTest.java:23)
enter code here
```

package com.jaxb;

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBTest 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        try
        {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.pain.jaxb.ver2.Document.class);           
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();         
            um.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");          
            com.pain.jaxb.ver2.Document PainTransferList2 = (com.pain.jaxb.ver2.Document) um.unmarshal(new FileReader("C:/WorkArea/JAXB/src/com/pain/messages/APXSEPAS_510812_1.XML"));         

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Please advice.

Thanks
Rafi

Comment: Can you try without setting the JAXB_ENCODING property? It is used for writing (marshalling) XML only, I think.

Comment: @Rafi - For more information on JAXB properties see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

Answer (score 7):

You're setting a `Marshaller` property on an `Umarshaller`:

```
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();         
um.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

You can only set `Unmarshaller` properties on an `Unmarshaller`.

Remove the `setProperty` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am writing a generic XML parser using JAXB for parsing ISO20022 credit transfers XML files. I have generated all the POJOS by using in built JAXB tool by feeding XSD into it for all the ISO versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am writing a generic XML parser using JAXB for parsing ISO20022 credit transfers XML files. I have generated all the POJOS by using in built JAXB tool by feeding XSD into it for all the ISO versions.  pain.001.001.01.xsd / pain.001.001.02.xsd / pain.001.001.03.xsd. I have clubbed and created a single package structure so that I can have only unique element to java objects created. Now at the runtime i am giving different Document class to the  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DocumentVer01.class);  Document class is different for each of the versions.

Comment: Hi I found the answer for this in the same forum. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1871060/907519