# MOXy JAXB javax.xml.bind.PropertyException

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I followed this example: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JSON_Twitter

Now I have this class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("http://test.url/path/to/resource");
        JAXBElement<Foo> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Foo.class);

        System.out.println(jaxbElement.getValue().getFoo());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }
}
```

And I have `jaxb.properties`:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(UnmarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.example.JavaSEClient.main(JavaSEClient.java:19)
```

**How can I fix this?**

I searched SO and Google, these answers are not working:

[PropertyException when setting Marshaller property with eclipselink.media-type value: application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498635/propertyexception-when-setting-marshaller-property-with-eclipselink-media-type-v)
[JAXB javax.xml.bind.PropertyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159675/jaxb-javax-xml-bind-propertyexception)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `jaxb.properties` file is in the same package as the domain classes you used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`, and that EclipseLink MOXy is on your class path.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/jaxb.properties

If you are using Maven, then the `jaxb.properties` file should be under the following location assuming `Foo` is in a package called `com.example.Foo`:

- src/main/resources/com/example/foo/jaxb.properties
- src/main/java/com/example/foo/Foo.class

For a full example see:

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I have another question, please help. I have a REST Jersey(2.7) server, which uses MOXy because I need entity filters. I want to make a REST client on android. I tried JBoss RESTEasy-mobile which was good for a while, but this uses Jackson, and MOXy and Jackson conflicts MAP<k,v>. So now I want to use MOXy on android, but it looks I cant. Can I? How can I solve this?

Comment: thank you for the hint with the package structure, much better then placing them in the source-folder!

Comment: You must place the jaxb.properties in the same file/package structure as the _model_ and not the marshaller code. In this example, `Foo` is the model, not the name of the marshaller demo. Running `System.out.println(jaxbContext);` really helps to debug (as was done in the blog demo). If you run that and do not see `class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext`, you are not loading the correct `JAXBContext`.

Comment: i have a springboot project, so i have controller, beans, application portal, where should I put this jaxb.resources then? Thanks!