# Jaxb generated xml - problem with root element prefix

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to generate xml using jaxb. I created xsd and generated java classes.
But when I generate xml, I am geeting prefix ns2 to the root tag, which I don't want.

ex: I want root tag to be

```
 <report>
   <id>rep 1</id>
</report>
```

, But getting as

```
<ns2:report>
....
</ns2:report>
```

In the generated java class, I gave annotation as `@XmlRootElement(name="report",namespace="urn:report")`

Can some one pls help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is your class:

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="report",namespace="urn:report")
public class Root {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Then it makes sense that there is a prefix on the root element, because you have specified that the "root" element is namespace qualified and the "id" element is not.

```
<ns2:report xmlns:ns2="urn:report">
    <id>123</id>
</ns2:report>
```

If you add a package-info class to your model, you can leverate the @XmlSchema annotation:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "urn:report",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Then the JAXB implementation may choose to leverage the default namespace, but note now all of the elements are namespace qualified which may or may not match your XML schema:

```
<report xmlns="urn:report">
    <id>123</id>
</report>
```

For more information on JAXB and namespaces see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: If there are two namespace in the object, it turns to be like `<Message xmlns:ns2="http://404story.com/Code" xmlns="http://404story.com/Order">`, then some part will use `<ns2:xxx`. Could you tell me how to remove the `ns2` prefix?

Comment: @navins - Can you post this as a new question?

Comment: ok, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518253/jaxb-generated-xml-remove-namespace-prefix

Answer (score 1):

The blog entry [Customizing JAXB](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/customizing_jaxb) shows the alternatives provided by implementing a `PreferredMapper` . Unfortunately it explains, that is not possible to fully suppress namespaces.

Comment: Thanks. Useful. But the preferred mapper changes the prefix, doesn't remove the prefix. At the bottom of the page, they are saying it is not possible t remove the prefix. I am trying on the work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277502/jaxb-how-to-ignore-namespace-during-unmarshalling-xml-document/2148541#2148541). It describes how to use a SAX Filter to remove any namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use this attribute in your root element of your schema: elementFormDefault="qualified"
So for instance:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the accepted answer did not work for me. I got success when I found solutions in some related stockOverflow questions involving [DelegatingXMLStreamWriter](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/DelegatingXMLStreamWriter.java) from cxf and a filter, [NoNamesWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222902/remove-namespace-prefix-while-jaxb-marshalling). The implementation I used with NoNamesWriter:

```
public class NoNamesWriter extends DelegatingXMLStreamWriter 
{
    @Override
    public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String local, String uri) throws XMLStreamException {
        delegate.writeStartElement("", local, uri);
    }   

    public static XMLStreamWriter filter(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) throws XMLStreamException {
        return new NoNamesWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
    }

    public NoNamesWriter(XMLStreamWriter writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

}
```

Invoke the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222902/remove-namespace-prefix-while-jaxb-marshalling), like:

xmlmarshaller.marshal(xc, NoNamesWriter.filter(new FileOutputStream(outfile, false));