# Remove namespace prefix while JAXB marshalling

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, marshalling, prefix

I have JAXB objects created from a schema. While marshalling, the xml elements are getting annotated with ns2. I have tried all the options that exist over the net for this problem, but none of them works. I cannot modify my schema or change package-info.java. Please help

Comment: Another solution mentioned here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/29945934/4745777][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29945934/4745777

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After much research and tinkering I have finally managed to achieve a solution to this problem. Please accept my apologies for not posting links to the original references - there are many and I wasn't taking notes - but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597035/823393) one was certainly useful.

My solution uses a filtering `XMLStreamWriter` which applies an empty namespace context.

```java
public class NoNamesWriter extends DelegatingXMLStreamWriter {

  private static final NamespaceContext emptyNamespaceContext = new NamespaceContext() {

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
      return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
      return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
      return null;
    }

  };

  public static XMLStreamWriter filter(Writer writer) throws XMLStreamException {
    return new NoNamesWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(writer));
  }

  public NoNamesWriter(XMLStreamWriter writer) {
    super(writer);
  }

  @Override
  public NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
    return emptyNamespaceContext;
  }

}
```

You can find a `DelegatingXMLStreamWriter` [here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/DelegatingXMLStreamWriter.java).

You can then filter the marshalling xml with:

```
  // Filter the output to remove namespaces.
  m.marshal(it, NoNamesWriter.filter(writer));
```

I am sure there are more efficient mechanisms but I know this one works.

Comment: in case you don't want to use cxf, import the jaxws-rtxxx.jar then using the standard jawx-ws does the same trick by code the following:                   class NoNamesWriter extends XMLStreamWriterFilter,

Answer (score 15):

For me, only changing the package-info.java class worked like a charm, exactly as zatziky stated :

package-info.java

```
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
 (namespace = "http://example.com",
 xmlns = {@XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://example.com")},
 elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package my.package;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

Comment: If you use xjc to generate jaxb artifacts from an xsd through a .xjb file, the package-info.java is genereated and you should not manually change it. If you use Maven to run xjc, you can use the the maven-jaxb2-plugi together with the https://github.com/Siggen/jaxb2-namespace-prefix. This allows to add namespace prefixes to the .xjb file (which is the input to xjc to customize how code is generated).

Comment: This is the cleanest solution for me as long you don't need to mix different element from different namespaces. This is always my preferred way than writing a lot of code.

Answer (score 5):

You can let the namespaces be written only once. You will need a proxy class of the XMLStreamWriter and a package-info.java. Then you will do in your code:

```java
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter writer = new Wrapper((XMLStreamWriter) XMLOutputFactory
                                                               .newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter));
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Collection.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(books, writer);
System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

Proxy class (the important method is "writeNamespace"):

```java
            class WrapperXMLStreamWriter implements XMLStreamWriter {

                   private final XMLStreamWriter writer;

                   public WrapperXMLStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter writer) {
                       this.writer = writer;
                   }

                     //keeps track of what namespaces were used so that not to 
                     //write them more than once
                   private List<String> namespaces = new ArrayList<String>();

                   public void init(){
                       namespaces.clear();
                   }

                   public void writeStartElement(String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
                       init();
                       writer.writeStartElement(localName);

                   }

                   public void writeStartElement(String namespaceURI, String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
                       init();
                       writer.writeStartElement(namespaceURI, localName);
                   }

                   public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
                       init();
                       writer.writeStartElement(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
                   }

                   public void writeNamespace(String prefix, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
                       if(namespaces.contains(namespaceURI)){ 
                           return;
                       }
                       namespaces.add(namespaceURI);
                       writer.writeNamespace(prefix, namespaceURI);
                   }

    // .. other delegation method, always the same pattern: writer.method() ...

}
```

package-info.java:

```java
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, attributeFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED ,
        xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix = "xsi")})
package your.package;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Comment: you save my life

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NamespacePrefixMapper` extension to control the namespace prefixes for your use case.  The same extension is supported by both the JAXB reference implementation and EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.4.0/JAXB_RI_Extensions/Namespace_Prefix_Mapper

Comment: Hi, I have been following your answers lately for my project which is building XML. I am using the `Moxy` to create XML using the `Marshalling` approach. For some reason, the generated XML takes the default namespaces such as `ns0, ns1, etc` even though I have provided my own custom prefix while creating the `QName`. Can you please have a look at this question and provide your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67553941/creation-of-qname-takes-default-namesapce-prefix-rather-than-the-provided-parame

Answer (score 0):

Every solution requires complex overwriting or annotations which seems not to work with recent version. I use a simpler approach, just by replacing the annoying namespaces. I wish Google & Co would use JSON and get rid of XML.

```
kml.marshal(file);

String kmlContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
kmlContent = kmlContent.replaceAll("ns2:","").replace("<kml xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\" xmlns:ns3=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:ns4=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0\" xmlns:ns5=\"http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2\">", "<kml>");
FileUtils.write(file, kmlContent, "UTF-8");
```