# JAXB vs XStream xsi type and xml name space

Tags: jaxb, xstream

JAXB is generating xml like below and this is not root element.

```
<Activitys xsi:type="Activity" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
--------
-----
</Activitys>
```

How can we display like below?

```
<Activitys>
    <Activity>
      ----
     </Activity>
</Activitys>
```

XStream lib is generating like above and need to same with JAXB.

Comment: Please see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222902/remove-namespace-prefix-while-jaxb-marshalling

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, now I got rid of xmlns. Now how to print xsi:type in next line.  From <Activitys xsi:type="Activity" >
--------
-----
</Activitys> to <Activitys>
    <Activity>
      ----
     </Activity>
</Activitys>