# How to disable xmlns targetNamespace in final XML with Jaxb2Marshaller in Java

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I have a perfectly working XML file writer class which writes a final XML file with Jaxb2Marshaller, with the following code:

```
final String XSD_FILE_NAME = myxsd.xsd
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setSchema(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xml/" + XSD_FILE_NAME));
marshaller.setContextPath("com.my.project.type");
marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(ImmutableMap.of(
        JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE,
        JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, XSD_FILE_NAME
));
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

// this is the way to write into cache for validation:
JAXBElement<MyFile> myFileToMarshall = new ObjectFactory().createMyFile();
try {
    marshaller.marshal(myFileToMarshall, new SAXResult(new DefaultHandler()));
} catch (XmlMappingException xme) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create exact xml file, because the data is not valid!", xme);
}

try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/tmp/file.xml")) {
    marshaller.marshal(myFileToMarshall, new StreamResult(fileOutputStream));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exact XML writing failed", e);
}
```

The beginning of the XSD looks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           targetNamespace="http://xmlns.myproject.com/v1"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.myproject.com/v1">
```

And the beginning of the final generated file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<eExact xmlns="http://xmlns.myproject.com/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="myxsd.xsd">
```

And what I want:

**I want to remove from the final file the `xmlns="http://xmlns.myproject.com/v1"` part, but be able to validate the final file with the XSD.**

Is it possible?

Comment: Why? Without the namespace it wouldn't know where to get the elements from and validation would fail.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is my task now, to remove that part from the final file, even if it is a stupid idea.

Comment: So your task is to create an invalid XML document?

Comment: Looks like. The third party program which will read the final XML is wrong, and they cannot modify it. That is why I need to modify the final XML.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222902/remove-namespace-prefix-while-jaxb-marshalling/22755785