# I dont want package-info.java while using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb2

What is alternative to **package-info.java** which is used for JAXB.
I don't want this class in project.What are alternative settings for jaxb to skip this?.
Thank you.

Comment: Why? What's the problem?

Comment: i just want to understand why it is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not necessary indeed. You use it if you want to avoid jaxb to put something strange in your code like ns2 or whatever.
If you don't like to see strange things in your xml you should put package-info.java in your packages to clearly define things: eg the namespace.

here's a clear example of what i mean [Jaxb generated xml - problem with root element prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312572/jaxb-generated-xml-problem-with-root-element-prefix)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have been generating JaxB objects using xjc command. Using `-npa` option serves the purpose.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html

This is also compatible with Java 11, when using the maven plugin `cxf-xjc-plugin`

Here is a sample to add arguments 
https://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html

```
<xsdOption>
    <xsd>${basedir}/.../yourXSD.xsd</xsd>
    <packagename>your.package.name</packagename>
    <extensionArgs>
        <extensionArg>-npa</extensionArg>
        <extensionArg>-no-header</extensionArg>
    </extensionArgs>
</xsdOption>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **no.nils.wsdl2java gradle plugin**  https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java

You'd better **add -xjc-npa** option like that:

```
wsdl2java {
    ...
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            [
                    '-xjc-npa',
                ...
            ]
    ]
}
```

A comprehensive list of options is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html