# Jaxb generated xml - remove namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

Using JAXB, when there is two namespace in the object, I added package-info.java in the pakage, it remove one namespace prefix, like this [Jaxb generated xml - problem with root element prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312572/jaxb-generated-xml-problem-with-root-element-prefix/4316283?noredirect=1#comment39813130_4316283)

My objects like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Message",namespace="http://404story.com/Order")
public class Root {
    private String id;

    private Codes codes;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Codes")
public class Codes {
    @XmlElement(name = "Code", namespace = "http://404story.com/Code")
    protected List<String> Code;
....
}
```

package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://404story.com/Order", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.xxxx;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

But when there is two namespaces, it turns to be like this:
`<Message xmlns:ns2="http://404story.com/Code" xmlns="http://404story.com/Order">`

and some part will use `<ns2:Code>xxx</ns2:Code>`. Could you tell me how to remove the `ns2` prefix? And put the namespace like:

```
<Message xmlns="http://404story.com/Order">
  <Codes>
    <Code xmlns="http://404story.com/Code">xxxx</Code>
    <Code xmlns="http://404story.com/Code">xxxx</Code>
  </Codes>
</Message>
```