# failed to unmarshall when the root element contains xmlns=

Tags: java, jaxb

When using jaxb, it failed to unmarshall when the root element containing xmlns. How to fix it without changing xml data?

Comment: Post your code and sample input XML.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277502/jaxb-how-to-ignore-namespace-during-unmarshalling-xml-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package level @XmlSchema annotation to set the namespace qualification:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.org/package",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know what does "elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED" mean here?

Comment: It means that that for this package all elements will be qualified with this namespace URI.  You can override this namespace URI in annotations like @XmlRootElement and @XmlElement.