# JAXB unmarshalling returns 'URI is not absolute' error

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, unmarshalling

I received following response from webservice, and am using following code to unmarshal the response, but it returns following error.

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  
                  /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SearchFlightsResponse xmlns="ElsyArres.API">
            <SoapMessage>
                <Username>TEST</Username>
                <Password>TESTs</Password>
                <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
                <ErrorMessage />
                <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
                <AppVersion>8.0.3</AppVersion>
                <Request>
                    <Departure>FDH</Departure>
                    <Destination>HAM</Destination>
                    <DepartureDate>2014-08-08</DepartureDate>
                    <ReturnDate />
                    <NumADT>1</NumADT>
                    <NumINF>0</NumINF>
                    <NumCHD>0</NumCHD>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <CarrierList />
                    <FareClasses />
                    <Providers />
                    <WaitForResult>true</WaitForResult>
                    <NearbyDepartures>true</NearbyDepartures>
                    <NearbyDestinations>true</NearbyDestinations>
                    <RROnly>false</RROnly>
                    <MetaSearch>true</MetaSearch>
                </Request>
                <Response>
                    <SearchFlightId>140514114543-02-43064-52</SearchFlightId>
                    <Roundtrip>false</Roundtrip>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Flights>
                        <Flight>
                            <Outbound>
                                <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                <Duration>01:45</Duration>
                                <FlightNo>3L370</FlightNo>
                                <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T06:10:00</DepDateTime>
                                <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T07:55:00</ArrDateTime>
                                <Legs>
                                    <Leg>
                                        <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                                        <FlightNo>3L370</FlightNo>
                                        <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                        <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                        <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                        <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                        <DepTime>06:10</DepTime>
                                        <ArrTime>07:55</ArrTime>
                                        <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                        <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                        <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                        <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T07:55:00</ArrDateTime>
                                        <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T06:10:00</DepDateTime>
                                    </Leg>
                                </Legs>
                                <Taxes>0</Taxes>
                                <FareADT>6500</FareADT>
                                <FareCHD>0</FareCHD>
                                <FareINF>0</FareINF>
                                <MiscFees>6400</MiscFees>
                                <Idx>307963</Idx>
                                <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                <FareType>Web</FareType>
                                <FareId>3L0</FareId>
                            </Outbound>
                            <BagFee>0</BagFee>
                            <CcFee>600</CcFee>
                            <HandlingFee>500</HandlingFee>
                            <TotalFare>12900</TotalFare>
                            <FlightId>140514114543-02-21212-2</FlightId>
                            <Link2Book>http://sample.com</Link2Book>
                            <Provider>ElsyArres</Provider>
                        </Flight>
                        <Flight>
                            <Outbound>
                                <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                <Duration>01:45</Duration>
                                <FlightNo>3L376</FlightNo>
                                <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T18:00:00</DepDateTime>
                                <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T19:45:00</ArrDateTime>
                                <Legs>
                                    <Leg>
                                        <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                                        <FlightNo>3L376</FlightNo>
                                        <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                        <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                        <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                        <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                        <DepTime>18:00</DepTime>
                                        <ArrTime>19:45</ArrTime>
                                        <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                        <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                        <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                        <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T19:45:00</ArrDateTime>
                                        <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T18:00:00</DepDateTime>
                                    </Leg>
                                </Legs>
                                <Taxes>0</Taxes>
                                <FareADT>10500</FareADT>
                                <FareCHD>0</FareCHD>
                                <FareINF>0</FareINF>
                                <MiscFees>6400</MiscFees>
                                <Idx>307964</Idx>
                                <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                <FareType>Web</FareType>
                                <FareId>3L0</FareId>
                            </Outbound>
                            <BagFee>0</BagFee>
                            <CcFee>600</CcFee>
                            <HandlingFee>500</HandlingFee>
                            <TotalFare>16900</TotalFare>
                            <FlightId>140514114543-02-21212-3</FlightId>
                            <Link2Book>http://sample.com</Link2Book>
                            <Provider>ElsyArres</Provider>
                        </Flight>
                    </Flights>
                </Response>
            </SoapMessage>
        </SearchFlightsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://testv80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.myProject.wegolo

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**Code**

```
        ...
        SOAPMessage sm = response;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        sm.writeTo(out);

        this.results = (SearchFlightsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(sm.toString(), SearchFlightsResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is what's causing you the problem:

```
JAXB.unmarshal(sm.toString(), SearchFlightsResponse.class);
```

The result of `sm.toString()` is going to be something like the following and not a `String` representation of the XML.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Message1_2Impl@693f23a2
```

What you are doing now is the equivalent of doing the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXB.unmarshal("com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_2.Message1_2Impl@693f23a2", Foo.class);  
    }
}
```

Which will return the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1095)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.toSource(JAXB.java:291)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:205)
    at forum23652823.Demo.main(Demo.java:8)
```

**Note**

The `String` parameter in the `JAXB.unmarshal(String, Class)` method is the location of the XML, and not the XML itself.  This is why the exception is complaining about a URI.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html#unmarshal%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 4):

The XML response you are receiving back from the SOAP service is not valid XML.  The xmlns attribute is required to be an absolute [URI](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

This means the namespace name must be in the form: `<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>`

In order for the XML to be valid, the service you are calling should be sending back `urn:ElsyArres.API` as the namespace value.

```
<SearchFlightsResponse xmlns="urn:ElsyArres.API">
```

Your package-info file would then look like the following:

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "urn:ElsyArres.API", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.myProject.wegolo

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

If you cannot get the service to fix the URI issue you can remove it while unmarshalling through the use of a SAXFilter.  Here is a great example that supports both adding and removing namespaces during unmarshalling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148541/73446

Comment: I changed it to ElsyArres.API but it is still throwing same error.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can not ask them to change their service, is there any way to handle the error?

Comment: Edited the answer to include how to manipulate the namespace before jaxb parsing.

Comment: I added the filter to the code but it runs into error, the new question is here, would you please have a look at it, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228672/cannot-remove-namespace-of-soap-response-using-saxfilter

Answer (score 0):

When doing unmarshalling I am parsing the xml file and giving the only class element.
For your case: give following string to unmarshaller, this saves you many boring errors.
After that, if you are getting an error you can try to remove xmlns="ElsyArres.API" also. Namespace things may generate errors too.

```
    <SearchFlightsResponse xmlns="ElsyArres.API">
        <SoapMessage>
            <Username>TEST</Username>
            <Password>TESTs</Password>
            <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
            <ErrorMessage />
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <AppVersion>8.0.3</AppVersion>
            <Request>
                <Departure>FDH</Departure>
                <Destination>HAM</Destination>
                <DepartureDate>2014-08-08</DepartureDate>
                <ReturnDate />
                <NumADT>1</NumADT>
                <NumINF>0</NumINF>
                <NumCHD>0</NumCHD>
                <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                <CarrierList />
                <FareClasses />
                <Providers />
                <WaitForResult>true</WaitForResult>
                <NearbyDepartures>true</NearbyDepartures>
                <NearbyDestinations>true</NearbyDestinations>
                <RROnly>false</RROnly>
                <MetaSearch>true</MetaSearch>
            </Request>
            <Response>
                <SearchFlightId>140514114543-02-43064-52</SearchFlightId>
                <Roundtrip>false</Roundtrip>
                <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                <Flights>
                    <Flight>
                        <Outbound>
                            <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                            <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                            <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                            <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                            <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                            <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                            <Duration>01:45</Duration>
                            <FlightNo>3L370</FlightNo>
                            <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T06:10:00</DepDateTime>
                            <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T07:55:00</ArrDateTime>
                            <Legs>
                                <Leg>
                                    <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                                    <FlightNo>3L370</FlightNo>
                                    <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                    <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                    <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                    <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                    <DepTime>06:10</DepTime>
                                    <ArrTime>07:55</ArrTime>
                                    <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                    <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                    <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                    <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T07:55:00</ArrDateTime>
                                    <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T06:10:00</DepDateTime>
                                </Leg>
                            </Legs>
                            <Taxes>0</Taxes>
                            <FareADT>6500</FareADT>
                            <FareCHD>0</FareCHD>
                            <FareINF>0</FareINF>
                            <MiscFees>6400</MiscFees>
                            <Idx>307963</Idx>
                            <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                            <FareType>Web</FareType>
                            <FareId>3L0</FareId>
                        </Outbound>
                        <BagFee>0</BagFee>
                        <CcFee>600</CcFee>
                        <HandlingFee>500</HandlingFee>
                        <TotalFare>12900</TotalFare>
                        <FlightId>140514114543-02-21212-2</FlightId>
                        <Link2Book>http://sample.com</Link2Book>
                        <Provider>ElsyArres</Provider>
                    </Flight>
                    <Flight>
                        <Outbound>
                            <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                            <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                            <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                            <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                            <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                            <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                            <Duration>01:45</Duration>
                            <FlightNo>3L376</FlightNo>
                            <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T18:00:00</DepDateTime>
                            <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T19:45:00</ArrDateTime>
                            <Legs>
                                <Leg>
                                    <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                                    <FlightNo>3L376</FlightNo>
                                    <DepCode>FDH</DepCode>
                                    <DepName>Friedrichshafen</DepName>
                                    <DestCode>HAM</DestCode>
                                    <DestName>Hamburg</DestName>
                                    <DepTime>18:00</DepTime>
                                    <ArrTime>19:45</ArrTime>
                                    <CarCode>3L</CarCode>
                                    <CarName>Inter Sky</CarName>
                                    <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                                    <ArrDateTime>2014-08-08T19:45:00</ArrDateTime>
                                    <DepDateTime>2014-08-08T18:00:00</DepDateTime>
                                </Leg>
                            </Legs>
                            <Taxes>0</Taxes>
                            <FareADT>10500</FareADT>
                            <FareCHD>0</FareCHD>
                            <FareINF>0</FareINF>
                            <MiscFees>6400</MiscFees>
                            <Idx>307964</Idx>
                            <FareClass>Economy</FareClass>
                            <FareType>Web</FareType>
                            <FareId>3L0</FareId>
                        </Outbound>
                        <BagFee>0</BagFee>
                        <CcFee>600</CcFee>
                        <HandlingFee>500</HandlingFee>
                        <TotalFare>16900</TotalFare>
                        <FlightId>140514114543-02-21212-3</FlightId>
                        <Link2Book>http://sample.com</Link2Book>
                        <Provider>ElsyArres</Provider>
                    </Flight>
                </Flights>
            </Response>
        </SoapMessage>
    </SearchFlightsResponse>
```