# ignore prefix (namespace) when unmarshalling xml

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:XXMsg xmlns:s="com:sample:test:msg">
    <s:Header>
        <s:cpyCod>xxx</s:cpyCod>
        <s:appCod>yyy</s:appCod>
    </s:Header>
</s:XXMsg>
```

and I want this to be unmarshalled into the following Java class:

```
public class XXHeader
{
    private String cpyCod;
    private String appCod;
}
```

I have written this code:

```
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
    try
    {
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory
            .createXMLStreamReader(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxmsg.xml"));
        while (streamReader.hasNext())
        {
            int next = streamReader.next();
            if (streamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT
                && streamReader.getLocalName().equals("Header"))
            {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XXHeader.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                XXHeader xxHeader = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, XXHeader.class).getValue();
                System.out.println(xxHeader);
                break;
            }
        }
```

I am getting all field values of `XXHeader` as `null`. But if I do change the xml and remove the prefixes `s:` in every element then I get the correct values.

How can I ignore this prefix while unmarshalling to get the correct values?

PS: Use of `@XML**` annotations in `XXHeader` class is discouraged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAXB: How to ignore namespace during unmarshalling XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277502/jaxb-how-to-ignore-namespace-during-unmarshalling-xml-document)

Comment: @Vadzim I had added the reference to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387115/725306) on the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277502/jaxb-how-to-ignore-namespace-during-unmarshalling-xml-document) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44431441/725306) below, so that certainly helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do this using `StreamReaderDelegate` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387115/725306):

```
public class XXHeaderXMLReader
    extends StreamReaderDelegate
{

    public XXHeaderXMLReader(XMLStreamReader paramXMLStreamReader)
    {
        super(paramXMLStreamReader);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeNamespace(int paramInt)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI()
    {
        return "";
    }

}
```

and adding the line in previous code:

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
try
{
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory
        .createXMLStreamReader(DocumentTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xxmsg.xml"));
    while (streamReader.hasNext())
    {
        int next = streamReader.next();
        if (streamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
        {
            if (streamReader.getLocalName().equals("Header"))
            {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XXHeader.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                XXHeaderXMLReader xxHeaderXMLReader = new XXHeaderXMLReader(streamReader);
                XXHeader xxHeader =
                    unmarshaller.unmarshal(xxHeaderXMLReader, XXHeader.class).getValue();
                System.out.println(xxHeader);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (XMLStreamException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (JAXBException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277502/jaxb-how-to-ignore-namespace-during-unmarshalling-xml-document) you may find useful information about ignoring namespace or you may define XML schema (with field description) and use it instead of `com:sample:test:msg`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. That was indeed helpful.