# Optional Namespace parsing XML via JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In my application user uploads several XMLs. Few XMLs that are uploaded do not contain a namespace tag and others contain it. I want to be able to support upload for both. JAXB is giving exception on former.

I want to able able to make namespace as optional ie support both files.

XML that is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:transforms xmlns:ns2="http://www.mynamesapace.com/xmlbeans/connectorconfig">
```

XML that is failing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transforms>
```

**Here is how I am unmarshalling the XML**

```
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transforms.class);
  Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  transforms = (Transforms) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

**This is my pojo**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "transforms", namespace = 
"http://www.mynamesapace.com/xmlbeans/connectorconfig")
public class Transforms implements ConfigDiffable<Transforms, 
ChangedTransforms> {
.....
```

**Update** :

If I remove

```
namespace = 
    "http://www.mynamesapace.com/xmlbeans/connectorconfig"
```

XML without namespace start working

Comment: Does any version work if you remove `namespace = ...` from the pojo?

Comment: I "namespace = " is removed the second one works

Comment: Which one is that? Do you mean the one without a namespace in the XML?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson  When there is no namespace in code the xml without ns works just fine . So I am able to support only one at one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class:

```
class XMLReaderWithoutNamespace extends StreamReaderDelegate {
  public XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(XMLStreamReader reader) {
    super(reader);
  }

  @Override
  public String getAttributeNamespace(int arg0) {
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public String getNamespaceURI() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Change your unmarshalling to:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transforms.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
XMLStreamReader xsr = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(is);
XMLReaderWithoutNamespace xr = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(xsr);
transforms = (Transforms) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xr);
```

I had no namespace defined in the pojo when I tested this.

Solution taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387115/1616627).